# Exclude certain lines from beeing formatted by notepad++ jstool

Tags: notepad++

I use notepad++ extension JStool ([www.sunjw.us/jstool/npp/](http://www.sunjw.us/jstool/npp/)) to format js code via ctrl alt m,

While the result is nicely formated, for certain lines of code I would prefer not to have  my own formatting destroyed.

Example: The definition of a large object. Here I would like to keep

```
control = {0:'NUL',1:'SOH',2:'STX',...,159:'APC',255:'DEL'};
```

instead of

```
control = {
    0: 'NUL',
    1: 'SOH',
    2: 'STX',
    ...,
    159: 'APC',
    255: 'DEL'
  };
```

just to keep the code clearly readable. Of course I could format all stuff before the line and all behind, but that would be a nuisance. Or I could format all objects in a single line, which is not intended.

Or in certain cases I'd like to write

```
     a = 12356;
   xyz =    22;
```

instead of

```
   a = 12356;
   xyz = 22;
```

Is there a way to instruct JSformat to exclude such lines?

Comment: Have you asked the developpers of JSTool?

Comment: No, I haven't. 
Maybe I should.

Comment: Hi, Paul
That is not able to.
Many thanks for using this plugin.
孙峻文
Sun Junwen